# How do I safeguard POST requests across multiple servers to make them temporarily idempotent?

Tags: http, idempotent

As we know, a POST method is not idempotent. Should a user send multiple requests in a short time, the operation would be repeated.
For example:

- POST request to create a submission is called by the user.
- Similar submissions are allowed by the server, so if a user sends the same request twice, the second doesn't fail due to a unique constraint violation.
- The user sends two requests by accident, creating two identical resources (save for the auto generated resource ID).

How do I avoid this, whilst ensuring my server can be scaled? If I only had one instance, I could add a temporary timeout list to the server which would prevent the user completing similar requests on the same server temporarily. However if the request got passed to a different server instance, this server would not have the user on the timeout list and would process the second request just fine.
I'm aware that I can implement something on the client side such as a temporary submission button disable so users can only send one request at a time, however is there a way to handle this on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't have much production experience in Web development.

If the goal is to safeguard from "Submit" key being pressed twice by accident, then I'd add a generated GUID to the POST web page somehow (a form field?). The posted contents and GUID form a unique key. It prevents the same contents from being submitted twice from the same generated page.

Comment: That kind of solution would be easier rectified by temporarily disabling the button once it is first clicked. One of the reasons I would like server side protection would be to prevent spamming from malicious agents, and being able to have server side functionality that blocks a user temporarily seems like the optimal solution.